# What's the logical flaw in Euclid's construction of the triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

NJ Wildberger [says in this video](http://youtu.be/GGj399xIssQ?t=3m36s) that there's a logical flaw in Euclid's construction of the triangle, that you're not really able to know (apart from the picture) if the circles intersect. He also provided no further comments about that. So, how's that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the speaker says: How do we know that the circles intersect?
The axiom system in Euklid's *Elements* is in fact not strong enough to show that these circles intersect. Essentially, there is missing a notion of "between" and completeness, which has been corrected later by Hilbert.
To see the problem immediately, note that you can do Euklidean geometry in $\mathbb Q^2$.

Comment: Could you explain which notion of "between" in the situation of Euclid would help guarantee that the circles do intersect, and which additional axiom is involved?

Comment: The mention to Hilbert's axioms was quite helpful, I've searched for it, [here it is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_axioms#The_axioms). From here I just need to research a little.

Comment: @Hagen I can't see the problem with the euclidean geometry in $\mathbb{Q}^2$

Comment: @GustavoBandeira The circle around $(0,0)$ through $(1,0)$ and the circle around $(1,0)$ through $(0,0)$ "should" intersect in $(\frac12,\frac{\sqrt3}{2})$, but that opint is not there in $\mathbb Q^2$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I added "completeness" as that is at least as important, I guess.

Comment: I've looked at the Wikipedia page on Hilbert's axioms, and I'm baffled. It looks like a complete mess, _especially_ completeness, which seems to be the axiom system reflecting on itself. But that may just be my first impression. In any case it is not clear to my how completeness can be invoked to decide which pairs of circles intersect and which don't.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: You can use geometric constructions to represent elementary arithmetic operations, so you can show that a subset of the plane has to be isomorphic to $\mathbb Q^2$. But you need the axiom of completeness (which I indeed understand to be second-order) to show that the reals, which you can define using limits, are included as well so the point of intersection which you can compute in real coordinates indeed has to exist.

Comment: @MvG: I've spent another half hour staring at those axioms (supposing WP hasn't distorted them too much) and there's plenty that I just can't understand. Notions like "segment", "angle", "side of", "ray" are neither primitive nor defined; it looks like nothing prevents all pairs of segments to be considered equivalent (but maybe III.6 is the clue). And I can get no idea of where to start proving a simple statement like "If $A,B$ are distinct points in a plane, there exists at least one point $C$ in that plane such that $AB$ is congruent to both $AC$ and to $BC$.

Comment: @Marc: I must confess I was relying on my other encounters about the relation between geometry and real numbers. Looking at the axioms in detail, I'm not so sure about my comment any more. On the one hand, the [first congruence axiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms#III._Congruence) should ensure that we can use the diagonal of any rectangle as a length on any line, so if we have $\mathbb Q^2$ we should be able to get $\sqrt3$ as well. On the other hand, I don't see how to deduce the existence of right angles from these axioms

Comment: I dont see how the logic holds here.  What does $\mathbb{Q}^2$ matter?  Why not $\mathbb{R}^2$?  The Euclidean plane is a continuous plane.  There are no numbers in the first place. Descartes combined the notions centuries later. Euclids construction does not require or rely on numbers.  These are geometric objects; an entirely different framework for thinking at the time. Its not wrong. We are the ones who are wrong for trying to overlay numbers onto it and then criticizing antiquity for... for what exactly?  Leave the algebraic geometry at home.

Comment: I think it was pretty clear in Euclids day that the circles intersected.  If each of the first two circles touch the others center then a part of each exists inside of the other.  Similarly a part of each exists outside of the other, as they have the same radius but are centered in different places: line AB intersects circle B(A) at a point C to the right of B that cannot be inside circle A(B), as AC is twice the length of the radius AB.  If two circles exist such that parts of each exist both inside and outside of one another then they must intersect. I think Euclid could have reasoned this.

Comment: Again, regarding the whole bit on rational numbers.  Its not applicable to Euclidean geometry.  Euclids geometry is based on two tools used on a plane, where lines/circles are drawn continuously and infinitely thin, infinitely long. Hyper idealized. There is no prohibition on rational or irrational coordinates, as coordinates are irrelevant to the axiomatic system.  Its only because of Euclids geometry that the Greeks came up with the concept of irrationals in the first place, by considering the length of the diagonal of a 1x1 square.

Comment: If they thought two circles intersecting was poor logic then they could have chalked up so many other discoveries involving irrationals up to a poor axiomtic system, and we may still not have it in our repertoire today.  The Greeks didnt lack rigor just because we have chosen to overlay a real number coordinate grid on top of the Euclidean plane. I dispute this is about rigor, but even if it was, we'd might as well discredit Newton too for lacking the "rigor" we demand today.

Comment: How many of todays mathematicians ought to lose credit in 100 years time when our rigor expectations shift again?  Its absurd.  I dont find the argument in the video convincing and in fact I find the attack on Euclids genius kind of insulting. And grossly dishonest coming from a supposed intellectual.

Comment: Euclid may not have had access to the modern real numbers, but his implicit assumption is that he is working in modern contiguous Euclidean space even if he was not able to say it that way. So, in a sense, his circles were in fact circles in $\mathbb R^2$ with all their uncountableness etc. He just didn't know how to describe them that way.