# Use of infinity as an "idealistic approximation"

Tags: examples-counterexamples, big-list, infinity

There have been several recent posts about the work of N. J. Wildberger, a finitist who seems to think that mathematics should only focus on things that have some sort of "real world" connection, which excludes many infinite objects in particular.  This viewpoint has some sympathy in the world of computation, for example, where algothims are a focus.  Some of these post have cause some controversy and discussion over on Meta: [On the closing of "Does mathematics require axioms?"](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9139/on-the-closing-of-does-mathematics-require-axioms)

For the record, my background is traditional and formalist, with a fairly typical amount of Platoism (I think natural numbers "exist" as much as anything mathematical exist).

I'd like to take a somewhat different tack to some of these issues, hopefully in a way that satisfies this site's goal of producing actual answers.  My question is:

**What are some examples where using "infinite" or arguably "unreal" mathematical objects does a better job of dealing with "real" objects?  I think of this concept as "idealistic approximation": when does idealizing a system make for better estimates?**

Here's my example to make this question concrete: *circles*.  Wildberger has problems with circles.  I believe one of the reasons is that, in real 2-space for example, the points of a circle would have many irrational (indeed, transcendental) coordinates, and the real numbers are a problem for him.  I'll go further: there are no actual circles in nature, best we can tell.  Anything that appears circular must have imperfections at some level of precision.  See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367378/whats-the-logical-flaw-in-euclids-construction-of-the-triangle) for an example.

The counter to this view is that any approach short of using an idealized perfect circle is *harder* than a more "realistic" approach.  By using unreal perfect circles, we obtain beautiful simple equations (for circumference, area, etc) that can be used for actual computations, which can be converted back to rational estimates to any desired degree of precision.  To try and address circles "realistically" from the start, taking into account their imperfections, is needlessly complex: it would inhibit understanding rather than aid it.

Another example question of this type asked for real world instances of limits, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365770/what-is-a-simple-example-of-a-limit-in-the-real-world/368873#368873).

The point is that finitist math is already embedded inside traditional math.  Finitists seem to think that the math outside of finitist hinders pedagogy.  I'd like the answers to this question to provide some counterexamples to this view.

Comment: Wikihammered by OP request.

Comment: Your circle example reminds me of an anecdote I heard on MO: Mathematician sits in his office. Mechanical engineer walks in and asks for help. Mathematician says, "Sure, how can I help you?" Engineer: "I need an explicit general closed formed expression for the Schwarz-Christoffel mapping for a regular polygon inscribed in the unit disc." Mathematician: "Oh that would be quite complicated. Can I ask why you need it?" Engineer: "Well, I really wanted the one for the disc. But I'm afraid it is too hard. So I figure I'll ask you for the polygon case and take $n$ to infinity."

Comment: @Willie Wong: Exactly. I fear that finitists would actually prefer the polygon approximation.

Comment: I have some inkling the tension really isn't about "ideal" vs "real", but is more about analytic versus synthetic reasoning, possibly with a dash of projecting onto the analytic approach one's frustrations with how difficult the subject of practical computation can be.

Comment: I think this piece of Wildberger has gotten a lot more attention here than serves any good purpose.  I read it -- and forced myself to read the whole thing because people discussed it here so much -- and while I hardly found anything outrageous in it, neither did it break any new ground when it comes to views of the infinite....

Comment: ....Also it is rather loosely written, to the extent that I suspect that people who are quoting it chapter and verse are simply wasting their time.  My own interpretations of various passages in the piece have been different from those of some others (and it's not that I insist I'm right; rather there is some ambiguity there).  In particular people have seized upon "real world mathematics".  I think Wildberger means by this what most mathematicians do -- i.e., the mathematics we actually think about and work on daily, which is usually far removed from slippery ideas about infinite sets.

Comment: As an example of a real-world mathematical fact, he cites that the exceptional Lie group $G_2$ has no $11$-dimensional irreducible representation.  Of course $G_2$ is not a "real world object" in the sense that most philosophers or physicists would mean.  Also it certainly seems to be an infinite object, so even calling Wildberger a "finitist" seems questionable.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: I basically agree, but I think at least two things are at work here. First, the idea of "real world" applications resonates. Second, what mathematicians mean by *rigor* and *formalism* is not well understood, let alone why it is important, outside of mathematics.  I believe Wildberger is arguing that the former is very important, and the latter is actually harmful.  I disagree, but this is the debate.

Comment: @trb456: Metaphysical questions about infinite sets may not be squarely on topic for math.se.  But if they are, surely it would help to focus on some of the classic writings in this area.  Wildberger's piece is certainly not one of them, in my opinion.  Why is this one unpublished, somewhat sloppily written article the focus of so much debate?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Because for the layman, infinity is weird, and so are the classical writings. And when you layer on the computation/complexity people, practicality seems reasonable.  This is specifically why I asked my question: when is "idealistic" reasoning (of the type that shows up in formalism) better at approximating reality than more discrete approximations?  This is just a variation of the pure/applied debate in hard sciences.  "Why am I funding pure research when I want applications?" Because pure research is a precursor for applied solutions. Remember, I'm a classicist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this point of view is of interest here, but the vast majority of physics conisists of simplifying assumptions.

Modeling fluid flow or elasticity without the fiction of a continuous media, in particular, is a clear example of a pedagogically insane approach. Of course there are errors in this approximation, due to endless small details, but these are generally best viewed as corrections to the continuous problem from the point of view of trying to understand any phenomenology at all.

More mathematically, the loss of the notion of completeness makes it very hard to distinguish between spaces where things converge and where they don't, so PDE theory probably goes out the window, along with spectral theory too.

Comment: Terrific stuff, thanks!  This is exactly what I would like to compile.

Answer (score 3):

Another example might be probability *density* functions, which are usually continuous real-valued functions.  One could argue that most "real" applications would require discrete random variables (to be computable, e.g.).  But as with the circle example, a continuous "approximation" of some complicated discrete random variable might be easier.  In particular, because of the Central Limit Theorem, many discrete probability distributions (formed by taking a random sample, say) rapidly approach a normal distribution under reasonable conditions.

Answer (score 1):

One example that's close to my field is how much simpler [dynamical systems theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_systems_theory) is in continuous time than in discrete time.  For example, the [Poincaré–Bendixson theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Bendixson_theorem) shows that continuous-time dynamical systems in less than three dimensions can never exhibit chaos; discrete-time dynamical systems can be chaotic in any number of dimensions, even just one.